# What is the value of the infinite nested radical $\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

The value is usually taken to be the limit of the partial sums as the number of terms increases beyond limit.  In this case each partial sum is trivially zero,  so the value of the infinite nested radical is to be taken zero.
However, if we let the value to be $x$, then
$x^2 = 0+ x$, which implies $x=1$.
So, what is the value, $0$ or $1$? And why should we prefer $0$ but not $1$?

Comment: *then x^2 = 0+ x, which implies x=1.* --- Another solution to $x^2 = 0 + x$ is $x=0.$

Comment: $x^2=0+x\implies x=0$ as well as $x=1$. Although $x=1$ is a potential answer, the radical will never converge to $x=1$, so it does not make sense to define $x=1$ as a solution to the problem

Comment: Since these aren’t sums, this isn’t a partial sum. But yes, the usual way is the define in terms of partial expressions and take the limit.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path and one evaluates that ... how? I don't see how to express the partial terms symbolically

Comment: @FShrike if it doesn't converge to 1, then why does the solution yield 1 as a potential answer? I mean, isn't it implicit in the equation that x is that value which is the limit of {a(n)} as n approaches infinity?

Comment: We get two solutions for $y=1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}},$ too, but only one of them is correct.

Comment: When dealing with infinities, it is essential to define what you mean by the problem, and what you mean by a solution. The most natural way to approach your problem is to say the solution is the limit of partial terms. Solving the equation algebraically as $x^2=0+x$ is taking the perspective that any solution is a fixed point of the function $\sqrt{0+x}$, and while $1$ *is* a fixed point, it is not a fixed point that the sequence converges to if you start from $0$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, such expressions can be considered sums, since whenever they are well-defined, they shall be real quantities.

Comment: No, a “real quantity “ is not always a sum. To say so is being pedantic to the point of invalidating language. @Allawonder

Comment: *then why does the solution yield 1 as a potential answer* --- The same question can also be asked when you get [an extraneous solution to a radical equation](https://www.google.com/search?q=extraneous+solution+radical+equations), something you've probably encountered before. Think of it this way: "IF the limit exists, and we call it $x,$ THEN $x^2=0+x.$" Note that this is a true statement. Also true is "IF the limit exists, and we call it $x,$ THEN $x^3+\sin x=5x,$" although there is probably no reasonable rationale for how one might stumble upon this second equation by algebraic steps.

Comment: The object written $\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$ is simply not well defined.  Rather, we begin from the inside with $x_0=a$ and define $x_1=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{x_0}}$.  Then, continuing, we have $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{0+\sqrt{x_n}}$ with $x_0=a$.  Letting $n\to \infty$ we find $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$ for $a>0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ for $a=0$.  This is the result that  Thomas Andrew posted.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, I don't know what you're talking about. But every real number is a sum of rational numbers. Do you deny this?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{0+x_n}.$

You easily get $$x_n=x_0^{1/2^n}$$

The limit of this expression is $1$ when $x_0>0.$

But the partial expressions here have $x_0=0,$ the only case that matters.

---

More generally, if $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ with $f$ a continuous function, then if $x_n\to x$ then $f(x)=x.$ But there might be multiple solutions to $f(x)=x.$ Which solution. Whether you get a limit, and if so, which limit, might depend on $x_0.$

---

If $a>0,$ the expression:

$$x=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\dots}}$$ gives two solutions, too:

$$x^2-a=x\\x=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1+4a}}2$$

The reason for two solutions when $a>0$ is that squaring both sides introduces the possibility that $x<0.$

So here, the sequence $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+x_n}$ always converges to the positive root, if it converges.

Comment: So, it leads to 0^0, which is undefined, am i right? Then why do we take 0 as the answer, sir?

Comment: $0^0$ came from where exactly? $0^{1/2}=0$ seems like the relevant thing here @AdNKhan

Comment: @AdNKhan: the question as stated is not stated correctly. As the answer shows, depending upon how the sequence is constructed (by taking $x_0\gt 0$ or $x_0=0$) the answer will be different.

Comment: $0^{1/2^n}=0,$ so it converge to $0.$ Whether $0^0$ is defined or not is irrelevant. (I prefer to define $0^0=1,$ but that does not affect the answer, since this is a limit, not the expression $0^0.$ @AdNKhan

Comment: "But the partial expressions here have $x_0=0$...". I don't think that it is right to make this claim unless explicitly stated in the question. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Partial expression, as I take it to mean, is cutting off the terms to some finite number of terms. It wouldn’t be a partial expression here if it had $x_0\neq 0,$ since there is no non-zero value in the expression. Now, whether that limit of partial expressions is the “meaning” of this expression depends. @Koro

Comment: It's also obvious for $x_0=0$ that $x_n=0$ for all $n$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} 0=0$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for making it clear!

Comment: @kingW3 your argument is short and sweet! Thanks. So I guess it is because we are taking the fixed number 0, rather than a vanishingly small x,  in which case the answer would be 1, I think.  Am i right?

Comment: @AdNKhan Sort of, since $x_0$ doesn't depend on $n$ or anything for that matter it's either $0$ or it's not so it can't be "vanishingly small". Now if you somehow did stumble upon a limit of the type $0^0$ the value wouldn't necessarily be $1$ or $0$ for example $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\log_x(k)} = k$.

Comment: @kingW3 No,  I meant not just the x in the innermost radical but if every 0 is replaced with x which tends to zero. In that case the value should be 1,no?

Comment: @AdNKhan Yeah, that seems about right you take the positive solution $x=(1+\sqrt{1+4a})/2$ and just plug in $a=0$.